# RedPitaya hello world hangs up a board

Tags: embedded-linux, fpga, xilinx, vivado, redpitaya

[image: RedPitaya LEDs blinking schwmatics]
I Tested a simple "hello world" application for RedPitaya FPGA: [RedPitayaHelloWorldVHDL](https://github.com/lvillasen/RedPitayaHelloWorldVHDL).
It takes a clock from PACKAGE_PIN U18 and U19, devides it by frequency to receive 1Hz, and outputs counter to LEDs. After making a bitstram and writing to FPGA by command:

```
 cat bitstram.bit > /dev/xdevcfg
```

LEDs blinks good, but Linux on board of RedPitaya hangsup. Why it's happening? and how to avoid it?

[image: RedPitaya LEDs blinking]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instantiate a Zynq "PS7" component in your design, that is the interface between the Linux SoC part and the FPGA fabric, there is also a wizard in Vivado to configure this. If this component is not in the design then programming the bitstream crashes the SoC.

If the Linux on Red Pitaya also assumes the presence of any AXI slaves on the FPGA fabric side, omitting these from the design might also cause a lock up, but this is less likely to be the problem.

Comment: David, great thank you dir your reply. Are you sure that ps7 is needed in all zyxq 7 projects? Exactly this example has no any interaction with PS7 CPU. No AXI and no other components. Only clock, from external source, frequency divider and output port for LED. FPGA fabric is self sufficient.  Why PS7 is needed for not hunging?

Comment: If the PS7 is not used, various signals end up at incorrect values which crash the CPU

Comment: thank you for comment. Minimum PS7, as I understand, consists only of clocking and fixed IO ports. Are you mentioned them in "various signals"?